# Ruby sleep or delay less than a second?

Tags: ruby

I'm making a script with ruby that must render frames at 24 frames per second, but I need to wait 1/24th of a second between sending the commands. What is the best way to sleep for less than a second?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

```
sleep(1.0/24.0)
```

---

As to your follow up question if that's the best way: No, you could get not-so-smooth framerates because the rendering of each frame might not take the same amount of time.

You could try one of these solutions:

- Use a timer which fires 24 times a second with the drawing code.
- Create as many frames as possible, create the motion based on the time passed, not per frame.

Comment: @Funkodebat I'm pretty sure every basic ruby runtime does this for you.

Comment: @JosephSilvashy: I don't have any insight into the ruby interpreter, but ruby mri does not do memoization by default. But I hope it does this kind of optimization while converting the source code to byte code.

Comment: It's a good idea to extract the 1.0/24.0 value to a variable for the DRY principle. Other pieces of code will need that value too, so you should keep it in a central location to avoid duplication. If performance is a side-effect, then great!

Comment: You should definitely extract the constant, and definitely not do it with the reason "all the performance you can get"

Comment: On a performance note, I was curious about this and wrote 2 quick functions. One that adds 1.0/24.0 to a variable 10 million times and another using a CONST equaling 1.0/24.0 10 million times. Then I ran those functions 100 times each and took the averages. Ran THAT script 4 or 5 times. Results: Using the constant vs recalculating provided about a 20% speed increase consistently in each trial.

Comment: But it's a quick division, ran once per frame. Hopefully the rendering of the frame itself is many magnitudes greater in computational complexity. This is a brilliant example of premature optimization.

Answer (score 120):

Pass a `float` to `sleep`, like:

```rb
sleep 0.1
```

Comment: Simple and efficient.
I love Ruby!