# sidetiq implement operation every half second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, recurrence, sidetiq

I have a job, which should be implemented every 500ms.

But, as I see, the smallest timeout is 1 second. How can I decrease this limit? Is there any functionality like this:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence do
    millisecondly(500)
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby sleep or delay less than a second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543034/ruby-sleep-or-delay-less-than-a-second)

Comment: How can I use this as a sidetiq job?

Comment: AFAIK Sidekiq is by default configured to check for incomping jobs every 15 seconds per process. Adjusting it to poll each half a second (that could probably allow you to do stuff like this) will greatly increase system load, I'd rather say Sidekiq is the wrong tool for the job here. I can't hint on what's right though.

Comment: D-Side, I said about sidetiq, not sidekiq

Comment: It's based on Sidekiq, what I said still applies.